# Getting secondary sidebar menu to remain highlighted while visiting page

Tags: css, menu, web, sidebar

I recently added a page to our website and how it originally is set up so the Top Nav remains hightlighted as well as the menu on the left hand side. I am just looking to get the "Employee training" on the left hand side to remain highlighted while on the page. If you browse the other pages under this section you will see what I mean. Thanks for the help!

http://www.petrowestcorp.com/employee-training/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have copied the Company Overview page to the Employee Training page and then made the necessary page changes.

The one change that you missed was within the

Remove the class from the first menu item (Company Overview) and put it in the last menu item (Employee Training)